# Opening VLC media player 3 takes a long time to open

Tags: windows, performance, vlc-media-player, speed, application-launch

VLC Media Player 3.0.8 is taking a long time to launch on my Windows PC.  It typically takes 6 seconds or more. I have a Win 10 machine with a class 50 SSD, Six Core Xeon 2.90GHz, etc. VLC launch should not be this slow.

How can I speed up the loading time of VLC?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There can be many causes for a slow launch in VLC 3, but here are two solutions I've confirmed help:

**Solution A**
VLCwin7User on the [VideoLan forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=144201) came up a solution that I will paraphrase and add to:

1. Bring up an administrative command prompt in the vlc.exe directory.  This would typically be `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC` for 32-bit, or  `C:\Program Files\VideoLan\VLC` for 64-bit.
   (To bring up an administrative prompt in this directory, open the Start menu and type `cmd`. Right click on `Command Prompt` and select `Run as administrator`.
   Then type `cd`, space, and then the VLC directory, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.)
2. Issue `vlc-cache-gen .\plugins` <kbd>enter</kbd>... which generates \plugins\plugins.dat

This brought launch time down to less than a second on my machine.

---

**Solution B**
This is the solution I had originally tried, but it only reduced the launch time by about 25%. I'm putting it here for completeness. I did not notice this making much difference after using Solution A from above.

1. Open VLC preferences via the menu or by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Select `show settings` > `All` from the bottom left corner
3. In the `Advanced` section, uncheck "Scan for new plugins"

[image: VLC launch time reduction setting]

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that pre-generating the plugins list noticably speeds startup,

Comment: Thank you ! Solution A worked perfectly. The question is why is this thing not automated ? ... or why this phenomenon even exist ?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Solution A worked for me!

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Went from ~10 seconds to less then 1.

Comment: Solution B worked for me and actually I was thinking that using VLC as portable is the source of this problem!