# VLC Taking MINUTES to open

Tags: windows-10, performance, vlc-media-player

To begin, love the product!
Now.... Recently re-installed Windows 10.  Downloaded and installed VLC Player (3.0.14 64bit).
I have the same version on other computers, runs no problem.  This one computer however,
when I try to run the program takes minutes.  When I say minutes I don't mean 1 or 2, I mean like 10 to 15 just to open the program.  I have also noticed that when I am in the programs folder (VLC) and I try to open one of the text files, say Authors.txt, it also takes an unreasonable amount of time. (I'm using Notepad++ but even regular notepad struggles opening anything in this folder)

This is the ONLY program doing this.  I have tried uninstalling multiple times.  I have even gone into the registry and scraped out any residual entries I could find from VLC.  I have even copied over a VLC folder from a PC I know is working well and pasted on this PC.  Same issue.

This was working on this computer, Windows died and I had to reinstall everything.

Any thoughts?  (BTW, VLC just opened.  It took 8:34 to open)

-Jeff

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening VLC media player 3 takes a long time to open](https://superuser.com/questions/1500375/opening-vlc-media-player-3-takes-a-long-time-to-open)

Comment: Per @DavidPostill I have seen windows machines with failing hdd take excessive time to access certain parts of the drive but never actually fail.  This was a rare situation but I can confirm even in the absence of errors.  The behavior of the txt file in combo with your app seems to support this.  Make sure you have a backup. Depending what tool you use to check your drive your results may vary.  I had a disk scan take a week and succeed on one of these drives.

Comment: I would lean towards harddrive failure too, based on what you've said.